# Java : add some text in a video?

Tags: java, video, video-processing

I have to code a program which record a video of a guy speaking in front of the webcam (no real problem for that), but the output file (the video, in MP4 format) have to countain a banner with the name of the guy. I have no idea how to do that : is there a way to include graphical elements (here, a banner with some text) once the video is recorded? Or to add it on the fly, while the video is being recorded?
Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can post-process it with a tool such as ffmpeg.

See this link, item No. 6 for use of the "drawtext" option.

[Drawtext Example](https://sites.google.com/a/asu.edu/wireless-video-sensor/video/how-to-setup-full-ffmpeg-tools-in-ubuntu-11-10/useful-ffmpeg-commands)

Comment: Not perfect, but Im not sure I can do better! I'll probably use a tool like that. Maybe mp4parser would be better, being a Java API?